# How to transfer a website with a *.gd-extention from united domains to Amazon Web Services?

Tags: dns, amazon-aws

I registered a domain with a .gd-extention on uniteddomains and want it to transfer to amazon web servers (aws).

The problem is that aws has 4 dns-domains for the website (for example .com and .net), but none has a .gd-extention.

What do I have to do to get this .gd on aws?

Answer (score 1):

Nameservers needn't have the same extension as the hosted domain, just use whatever amazon throws at you

Comment: That means: when my Domain at United Domains is xyz.gd, at Amazon Web Servers I can use a xyz.com? That works?

Comment: your own domain stays xyz.gd. the nameservers should look like ns1.something.com, ns2.something.com etc

Comment: so in the Internet i can call with the nameserver at aws my domain xyz.gd? Do you know how to transfer the xyz.gd to aws? With authcode?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Procedures may vary, better to follow specific instructions from your registrar.